# grid_slaves equivalent in Canvas in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I'm trying to access an item in `Canvas` in `tkinter`, like I can in a `Frame` using `grid_slaves()`

Let's say for example I want to access a subwidget:

```py
subwidget = Frame.grid_slaves(row=0, column=0)[0]
```

I can't use `grid_slaves()` on a `Canvas`, and I was wondering what the equivalent would be for something like:

```py
object = Canvas.grid_slaves(row=0, column=0)[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the canvas method `find_all` along with the canvas methods `type` and `itemcget` to get the information you need.

```
for item in canvas.find_all():
    if canvas.type(item) == "window":
        print(f"item id: {item} widget: {canvas.itemcget(item, 'window')}")
```

If you give all of the items you want to find a unique tag, you can use `find_withtag` to return only the items with that tag.